# Sony a7 III vs a7R III + Lenses

Tags: lens, sony-alpha

I think this question has been asked plenty of time.

**Camera?**

I am planning to buy a Sony FF camera next month and I am confused between buying the a7III vs a7rIII. The price of A7 III is 1455 euros and the a7r III is 1859 euros.

**Lenses?**

For lenses, I watched plenty of youtuber video showing the benefits of each lens for Sony FF camera but as I have a limit budget I am thinking get in first class the Sony 85mm 1.8 (459 euros) and Tamron 28-75mm f/2.8 (659 euros).

Because of the 28 focal length of Tamron I am planning to complete my lenses collection with Tamron 17-28mm (759 euros) after few months.

I found also the Sony 24-105mm f/4 (919 euros) not bad but I think that f/4 in low light situation could be an issue.

**In what situation I am shooting?**

Me and My wife are planning to launch a new brand of clothes, so our goal in first class is shooting people with those clothes in different situation: Indoor, Outdoor situation. We like shooting next to Monuments places like Eiffel Tour, Louvre. Those pictures will be posted in social networks like Instagram, SnapChat, etc, and In our Website.

For me I have a passion for cinematography (I will buy the Rohn S Gimble also), so my goal is to make a cinematic video for our Brand.

**Questions:**

What do you think is best for me? Is a7r III worth it? What’s the best lenses fit my requirements ? Thanks (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently owning the a7 III, the Tamron 28-75 2.8 and the Sony 85 1.8 which is at the center of your question.

**Camera**

The decision between the a7 and the a7r model is he first you should make:
Both cams share a lot of traits, however there is more difference than just resolution.

**Advantages of the a7 III**

- Slightly better performance in low light due to bigger pixels
- Better coverage of AF points and generally slightly more modern AF system
- Better suited to video as it does not use pixel binning and uses the full frame

**Advantages of the a7r III**

- Better resolution (a plus for product photos) and pixelshift as option
- Better viewfinder and rear monitor resolution (that one is REALLY noticeable, you can barely judge sharpness on the a7 III)
- You can use the APS-C mode and still have enough resolution to use the shot.

So you have traits that speak for each model. The a7r seems to be the better choice if you tend to the still photography, while the a7 is clearly the better choice for video.

**Lenses**

The Sony 24-105mm f/4 is a glorious lens, but as you already found out, the limitation is in the aperture. If you plan getting the 85mm and the 28-75mm it does not add very much to the mix.

**Sony 85mm**

This lens is just awesome - especially for the price. It is razor sharp, light, ok bokeh, super fast AF, good build quality. You cannot go wrong with this one.

**Tamron 28-75mm**

Another very good lens. The cheap price is ridiculous for what you get: Very good sharpness through all the range, fast AF, ok for video, light, good build quality.  Drawbacks are the limit to 28 instead of 24mm on the short end and the mediocre bokeh, when you shoot wide open. Still the best lens in that range for the price. And the nearest focus distance of that lens is so small, that you can literally bump into your subject. Which is really really cool.

Note: There is a new Sigma coming out, which also is supposed to be very good. But as with all Sigmas - it will be heavy.

**Personal thought**

I would propose to buy the Tamron and the Sony 85mm. If you can only afford one lens, pick the Tamron first. 75mm at 2.8 is a decent focal length for portraits as well. The 85mm will supply better bokeh and better sharpness, but is less flexible.

Then as a secondary step, I would evaluate what you have missed most during your first shots and then either invest into a wider lens, or a 70-200 2.8 (Tamron is planning a 75-180mm 2.8 in Spring 2020, it remains to be seen if that one is any good) to expand your options.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I fully agree with you. I think I will go with this gear for the moment : Sony a7 III, Tamron 28-75mm f/2.8, Sony 85mm f/1.8 and DJI Ronin S